# Hibernate: how to get time gap between two Date columns?

Tags: java, hibernate, date, criteria, restriction

For example, my columns look like

`1990-02-13 00:00:00.0` and `2015-02-19 00:00:00.0`.

How can I get the time gap (difference) in days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL dialect for Hibernate you can use the following functions,

unix_timestamp(datetime_value) - to take the difference between two columns

current_date() to get the current date. 
a list of reference functions could be found here

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/11953/MySQLDialect.java

For the second question can you try using

```
criteria.add( Restrictions.le("date_column", current_date() ) )
```